# Plugged in computer, sparks went off in outlet, now 2 rooms are without electric

Tags: electrical, repair

I plugged in a computer and spark went off. Now electricity is off in two rooms. Checked breaker it is fine. No electric coming in to outlets. I reset breakers 5 times.

Comment: If your breaker keeps tripping, then something is likely wrong and the breaker is trying to keep you from burning down your home or killing someone. Resetting the breaker again in that situation is a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: My breaker is not tripping.since i saw sparks coming from outlet.  electricity is out in two rooms.  I pulled out all outlets and none have electricity coming in.  Don't know were to go from here. 2 1/2 rooms.

Comment: Call in an expert - hopefully an electrician.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree that calling in an electrician is your best bet. The problem is most likely in the first dead receptacle or the last working one. The trick is knowing where to look and for what. I suspect a failed back-stab connection in a receptacle.

There also me be other problems you can't see. Best to have it all looked over.

Comment: Changed 10 outlets. went back to the closest one working and change that.  check breaker box again. didn't find a different breaker box nor did I find the open neutral. didn't find any back-stabbed receptacles

Comment: Are you sure you found all on that circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Often, they use light fixture boxes as terminal points for several branches. If there were a weak connection in one of those junction boxes, the jolt from the temporary short circuit you had when it sparked, may have blown that weak point open. They also hide junction boxes behind flat plates in sometimes obscure places (like under the stairs). The problem could be in one of those.